# How to check another event occurred rather than the expected return code?

Tags: android, startactivityforresult

I use startActivityForResult with an intent and a specific REQUEST_CODE to launch activity B from A.

In activity B the user can edit the database entry, or delete it.

If I press the same button, and launch the activity using the same request code and intent,

how can I check if the user chose to save the entry they edited, or delete it?

Comment: I would use a different REQUEST_CODE (that's what those are for) but in any case, when you specify a result, you can pass an Intent, and in that intent you can pass a KEY to indicate what you did...

Comment: Thanks @MartinMarconcini. If the user chooses to delete the entry, I instead pass an intent which contains a boolean with a "toBeDeleted" key. In both cases `resultCode == RESULT OK`, but I distinguish between saving/deleting using that boolean.

Comment: Did that work then?

Comment: @MartinMarconcini yes, I believe the data base is properly updated, because if I move back to A and reopen B, it reopens with the new data. What remains to be done is to refresh B without going back to A.

Comment: Good, I'll post an answer, you can mark it as resolved if that worked (I don't mind).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As stated in the comments, I'd personally use different REQUEST_CODEs for different operations, but if you truly want to respond with the same one, and indicate something, simply pass a boolean (or any other useful type) in the response's intent that you can handle in the `onActivityResult` in the calling activity or fragment.